# search series values for substring, if found remove string and leave value blank

Tags: python, pandas

looking for a way to have a list of keywords and search columns values for these keywords.  If keyword is found, then remove the entire string from the series and leave blank. In searching this it seem that many want to drop the entire row. I just want to drop the column cell value.

Some Context:
This column contains email addresses. Sometimes if email is not available then the people just put some form of (n/a, N/A, na, na@na.com, etc...). However, there are many ways this can be typed and also mistype'd (n/A, na@Na.c, a@n.co, n@n, etc....). So, I'm looking for an ideal to catch all that I can I remove the entire string(value).

My Logic: Create a list of keywords of different combinations(could be long). If keyword is found, then remove all string value.

```
keywords = ('na@', 'na.c', 'na@na.c', 'n@n', 'na@na.com', 'NA@')
df['column1'] = df['column1'].str.contains(keywords,"")


# This works but is going to take out a bunch of chained replace statements to get each item.
# also just removes keyword and might have extra characters left in string.
cols = ["column1","column2","column3"]
df[cols] = df[cols].replace('n/a', '').replace('N/A', '').replace('na@na.com', '')


# Works but just handles two conditions only 'na' & 'NA'
df['column1'] = df['column1'].str.replace(r'na',"", case=False)



Starting with:                   Finished:
column1                          column1
tom@gm.com                       tom@gm.com
na@na.com                        
n@n                                 
hazy@aol.com                     hazy@aol.com
n@.co                            
d88@yah.com                      d88@yah.com
a@na                             
nA@                              
chip@gm.com                      chip@gm.com
```

Hope this makes some sense. Please let me know if you need any further info. I appreciate any help that you can provide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

I would place my keywords inside a Set rather than a tuple, since Sets have O(1) lookup speed.
I would then create an empty list and iterate through the words and replace them if need be.

```
### This is to replicate your scenario

import pandas as pd


keywords = {'na@', 'na.c', 'na@na.c', 'n@n', 'na@na.com', 'NA@', "a@na", "nA@"}
column1 = {"column1": ["tom@gm.com", "na@na.com", "n@n",
                       "hazy@aol.com", "n@.co", "d88@yah.com",
                       "a@na", "nA@", "chip@gm.com"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=column1)

### End

# ACTUAL CODE
# this is where we will store the newly created words
replaced_emails = []
for email in df["column1"]:
    if email in keywords:
        # email is not valid therefore replace the invalid email with ""
        clear_email = email.replace(email, "")
        replaced_emails.append(clear_email)
    else:
        # valid email
        replaced_emails.append(email)
df["column1"] = replaced_emails

print(df)
```

If you want to do the foreach loop in one line you can use list comprehension i.e.

```
df["column1"] = [email.replace(email, "") if email in keywords else email for email in df["column1"]]
```

You might want to put some type of validation on the form so the user can only enter either a valid address or just simply N/A if one isn't available

Comment: Thank RamWill for the exceptional fix for this issue.  Works like a charm.  I do like the fancy one-liner but need to learn how to understand it better. Thanks for the walk thru. Also, I would love some validation checks in place however, I do not have control of that company's software and have to jump through hoops to get them to do anything. I'm just the "Cleaner".  Thanks for your help!!!